# Compilation error when initializing struct

Tags: c++, struct

For the life of me, I am unable to fix the compiler error. I have no idea what the error message means and the code looks fine to me. When initializing the list of vertexes, does the compiler interpreted lines like `vec3d(0.0, 0.8, -0.1)` as members of `vec3d` class thus I got the error?

```
#include <iostream>

class vec3d
{
public:
    vec3d(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        _x = x; _y = y; _z = z;
    }
private:
    double _x, _y, _z;
};

struct WireframePolygon
{
    int vertexes;
    int edges;
    vec3d vertex[50];
    int edge[50][2];
};

const vec3d v1 = vec3d(-0.5, -0.5, -0.1);

const WireframePolygon Trig = {
    6,
    9,
    {
        v1, // 1
        vec3d(0.0, 0.8, -0.1),   // 2
        vec3d(0.5, -0.5, -0.1),  // 3
    },
    {
        {0, 1},
        {1, 2},
        {2, 0},
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
debug.cpp:37:1: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'vec3d'
   37 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
debug.cpp:37:1: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'vec3d'
debug.cpp:37:1: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'vec3d'
...
debug.cpp:37:1: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'vec3d'
debug.cpp:37:1: error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'vec3d'
```

Comment: `vec3d vertex[50];` expects **50**, and you only gave it **3**.  (Because `vec3d` does not have a *default constructor* to supply the other **47**.)

Comment: A better option may be to use `std::vector` instead of an array. Hard to say for sure without more information.